# What does the Axial Diffraction pattern of a point source look like?

Tags: optics, diffraction

> The axial diffraction pattern of a point source is not disk-shaped, but has the hourglass shape or flare of the point spread function image in the x-z or y-z planes. - [Source](http://www.olympusmicro.com/primer/digitalimaging/deconvolution/deconresolution.html)

Is there a diagram of this? What does it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with answering you question with a diagram is that you are asking about a three dimensional situation where at each position an intensity is defines so to draw an appropriate graph you need to be living in a five spatial dimension world.

[image]

Normally one is just interested in the resolving power in the focal plane but in microscopy depth of field is also important and so one must consider the axial resolving power.

[image]

If you have a point object the diffraction pattern produced by an otherwise aberration free lens system could be represented as shown below.

[image]

This is the type of pattern described in the passage provided by the OP.

If you rotate the right-hand contour diagram about the axial axis that will give you the intensity distribution shown in the left-hand diagram.

The source of the information cited by the OP is an excellent one and here is a [sequence of diagrams taken from that source](http://olympus.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/imageformation/depthoffield/index.html) which I have collated to show the intensity pattern along planes which are parallel to the focal plane of the lens system the last of which is the familiar Airy pattern.

[image]